# Android Google Map api v2 returns null?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have below code and its working nice tvTitle is not returning null but

```
RelativeLayout relmain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainview);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

RelativeLayout contents = (RelativeLayout) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.placedetail, null);
relmain.addView(contents);

TextView tvTitle = (TextView) contents.findViewById(R.id.tvdealtitle);
                               ^^^^^^
```

but google map is return me null...check below code...

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();


System.out.println("Google map is :: " + googleMap);
```

**placedetail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgmap"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/banner"
    android:onClick="onClickBack" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/directions"
        android:onClick="onClickImage" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/reldetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdealtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdealoffertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvdealtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvdealtitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="offertext"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdealdesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvdealtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvdealoffertext"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="desc"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/reldetail" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is possible that you are calling `getMap()` too soon, perhaps before the fragment has been called with `onCreateView()`.

Comment: i call gmap initialize after oncreate completion end of oncreate.i want to show mapview and above mapview there are three textview but google map getting null, show how can i get googlemap using `contents.findViewById` , show above code `tvTitle` is not getting null but googlemap getting null...

Comment: i mean `GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().content.
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
` but its give me error

Comment: Where are you running the getMap call? From the activities onCreate?

Comment: yes from activity oncreate but problem due to inflator of layout, how can i get from `contents` ? show tvTitle is not null because findview from contents and googlemap is not working

Comment: It's a really weird way to add views to existing layout. Why do you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [SupportMapFragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html):

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists. This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view; however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

Then, in your Activity you can use [GooglePlayServicesUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html) to check about the availability:

```
// Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

// Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
if (mMap != null) {
    // Setup your map...
} else {
    int isEnabled = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isEnabled != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isEnabled, this, 0);
    }
}
```

[Here in method setUpMapIfNeeded](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/tourGuide/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nbempire/android/tourguide/component/activity/MapActivity.java) you've got a working example of one of my apps: [Tureame](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nbempire.android.tourguide).